# how to call java method from shell scripts

Tags: java, bash, shell, sh

I want to call this class from shell scripts:

```
public class EffectedUsers {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException, SQLException {
        appendProcessedUsersCount();
    }

    public void appendProcessedUsersCount()
    {
        System.out.println("hello world");
    }
```

I have tried with many ways and finally with the below code but nothing is working ..
Please help..

```
#!/bin/bash 
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_02 
CLASSPATH=/home/freddy/myapp/lib/EffectedUsers.jar: . 
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -cp $CLASSPATH EffectedUsers
exit 0
```

Comment: Re `nothing is working` try to be more specific on exactly what is the behavior you get, vs what you would expect to get. This will increase the likelihood of someone finding the answer.

Comment: Remove the space from your `CLASSPATH=` line.  The period (`.`) should come immediately after the colon (`:`).

Comment: Or, save it as a runnable jar file and just call it like java -jar file.jar